# How to create a segue performing a transition to the same view with another model object?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I am writing an iOS / CocoaTouch app and I am facing the following problem :

- I have a detail view (think of an overview of one given object)
- This detail view can present other elements
- Any of these other elements can be viewed in this exact same detail view (I mean, another instance of this view / view controller using the viewed object model.

The only problem I have is that I am not able to create a segue from a view to the same view in the storyboard editor. Therefore, I cannot create the segue at all, cannot assign an identifier, and thus cannot trigger it from code.

Is there any way to implement this ? 
This is as simple as a detail view pushing another, each of them having one dedicated instance of the view controller with their respective object model.

Thank you so much, I looked everywhere and cannot find any topic related to this.
Christophe.

Answer (score 2):

Segues are between view controllers, not views (even though a view can act as a trigger).  If you want to have a segue to a new view controller, create a new instance of it in the storyboard, assign its identity to the same class as your original detail, and define the segue.

If you're only trying to change which view is displayed inside a single view controller, then selectively setting views hidden and not-hidden can work...or adding/removing sub-views.

Comment: I did not know that I could put several instances of the same view controller on the storyboard. This way I can properly add a segue to a new controller instance.
The problem is that it seems to "copy" the associated view. That is to say that if I modify a control (label, button, image) on my first view, the second instance is not synched. 
This is not what I want, I would like to have exactly the same controller and view. I would like to be able to create a segue from a controller to itself with same associated view.